# AttributeError: type object ' ' has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

My code runs into an AttributeError and I don't know how to fix it

this is my class:

```
class Reservation:

    def __init__(self, passengerName, departureCity, destinationCity, dateOfTravel, timeOfTravel, numberOfTickets):
        self.passengerName = passengerName
        self.departureCity = departureCity
        self.destinationCity = destinationCity
        self.dateOfTravel = dateOfTravel
        self.timeOfTravel = timeOfTravel
        self.numberOfTickets = numberOfTickets

reservationList = list()
```

```
with open("reservation.txt", "w") as file:

    for reservation in reservationList:
        reservation.write(reservation.passengerName + "," + reservation.departureCity + "," + reservation.destinationCity +
                            "," + reservation.dateOfTravel + "," + reservation.timeOfTravel + "," +
                            str(reservation.numberOfTickets) + "\n")

    file.close()
```

```
File "C:/Users//Desktop/pld/ticket_reservation5.py", line 183, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users//Desktop/pld/ticket_reservation5.py", line 176, in main
    reservation.write(reservation.passengerName + "," + reservation.departureCity + "," + reservation.destinationCity +
AttributeError: type object 'Reservation' has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your individual Reservation objects don't have write attributes. You want to call the file's write method and use the object's data to populate the string.

```
with open("reservation.txt", "w") as file_:
    for reservation in reservationList:
        file_.write(reservation.passengerName + .... + "\n")
```

Side note, since you're using a context manager (with open() as _), you don't have to do `file.close()`. The manager will do it for you.

Also, `file` is a builtin so you don't want to overwrite that. You'll want to append a single underscore to the variable name to differentiate it [as described in PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

Comment: `file` is not a built-in in Python 3.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: probably PyCharm is used which is not clever enough to figure it out and completely relies on `typeshed`

Comment: @lés No problem. If this or any other answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: done! I have another question though, everytime i write a new reservation into the file, it writes multiple copies of the line i wrote. how can I fix this?

Comment: @lés That's strange, and shouldn't happen. I recommend printing out the list before writing to make sure the contents are what you expect (no duplicates in the list which make it look like one line is getting written multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

reservation is just a iterator to traverse through the list reservationList,it doesn't have any write functions defined .
    There are three ways to read data from a text file.

```
read() : Returns the read bytes in form of a string. Reads n bytes, if no n specified, reads the entire file.

File_object.read([n])

readline() : Reads a line of the file and returns in form of a string.For specified n, reads at most n bytes. However, does not reads more than one line, even if n exceeds the length of the line.

File_object.readline([n])

readlines() : Reads all the lines and return them as each line a string element in a list.

  File_object.readlines()
```

here is an example for opening a file and reading it:

```
file1 = open("myfile.txt","r") 
print(file1.read()) 
print(file1.readline())
```

Comment: You're opening in write mode, so you can't read from the file.

Comment: thank you for the info. i understand file handling in python a little better now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this and make sure your last string in your list has a `\n`so that it every time a different user put in information it writes in a new line:

```
with open("file_name.txt", 'a') as f: # "a" is used to append data to a file that is it
# does not delete previously written data instead appends to it also f is the variable 
# which stores the file and could be anything
    for reservation in reservationList:
        f.write(reservation)
    print("done")
```

Comment: Using "with" like done in the above method, you get better syntax and exceptions handling and is more pythonic

Comment: it works. but everytime i write a new reservation into the file, it writes multiple copies of the line i wrote. any idea how to fix this?